# Dotdeb php5-gd without libjpeg8?

Tags: debian, dotdeb, php5-gd

I have problem with GD - it creates blurry images on my dotdeb nginx+fpm server. I checked phpinfo and the difference is that the working servers show "libjpeg version: unknown". This faulty one shows "libjpeg version: 8". [see this diff](https://gist.github.com/tomasfejfar/9900790) (please note that the exact same code works fine on localhost and apache and breaks on nginx)

Is there a way how to use dotdeb php5-gd without libjpeg (as I do on my Apache server and on localhost), that works fine. Or is is because of a wrong configuration somewhere else?

Comment: How are you creating the images? This is more likely an issue with your code.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me the right direction. It was actually because I was using `imageconvolution($this->getImageResource(), array( array( -1, -1, -1 ), array( -1, 24, -1 ), array( -1, -1, -1 ),), 16, 0);` ... question is why did it work before?!

Comment: You'll have to ask that one on [so], I suspect. :)

Comment: not sure - the question would probably be "why does it work without libjpeg but not with" and the answer would be "it's obviously a server configuration issue, ask on serverfault" :D

Comment: I doubt that you are actually _without_ libjpeg. But since you didn't provide any information about the PHP build, it's really impossible for us to know.

Comment: I'll be happy to provide anything that would help you: `PHP Version => 5.5.10-1~dotdeb.1` - I haven't build the php myself - i used at repo from dotdeb

Comment: The build of the "working" server is more interesting.